# Run macro faster

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this macro for loading the data from multiple Excel files to one master table. This code is shorten than actual code. In reality I have more rows starts with GetData myFile. The code is repeating and I assume there is a better way to run this macro faster.

```
Sub Recurse2()
Dim DSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder, mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim myFile As File
Dim sPath$: sPath = "\\zts-fs1\kv$\Merné\Naposledy_merane_zily\"
Dim R$
Dim i As Integer
Dim test As String

test = "Otvor test!"
R = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("linky_zila").UsedRange), "|")
Set myFolder = DSO.GetFolder(sPath)
For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
        DoEvents
        If Not (InStr(1, R, myFile.Path) > 0) Then

            GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "D4:D5", Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False

            GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "S4:S5", Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)), True, False

            GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "A8:A9", Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)), True, False

            GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "E8:E9", Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4)), True, False

            GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "F8:F9", Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5)), True, False


            Sheets("test_zila").Range("U3", "U50000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm"
            Sheets("test_zila").Range("V3", "V50000").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

            Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 25), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 25)).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & myFile.Path & """ ,""" & test & """)"

            Sheets("linky_zila").Cells(Sheets("linky_zila").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = myFile.Path
            R = R & myFile.Path & "|"

           For i = 1 To 23
               If Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i), Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i)).Value = "" Then
                   Sheets("test_zila").Range(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i),   Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Sheets("test_zila").Cells(Rows.Count,  1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i)).Value = "/"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
Set DSO = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set mySubFolder = Nothing
Set myFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You should gather all the data you need and store it in an object array. One you have all the data you need, you should then write out that data in one go. That will speed things up dramatically.

Comment: Please do some research. [This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+make+macros+fastet&rlz=1CDGOYI_enVN604VN604&oq=stackoverflow+make+macros+fastet&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-US#hl=en-US&q=stackoverflow+make+macros+faster&spell=1) returned more than 10 questions on stackoverflow alone. One classic is to turn off screen updating while the macro is running, I.e. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `= True` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Application.ScreenUpdating=false as nhee says and replace some values with a With...End With statement, in order to be more readeable and slightly faster. And pre-calculate Rows.count!:

```
Sub Recurse2()
 Dim DSO As New FileSystemObject
 Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder, mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
 Dim myFile As File
 Dim sPath$: sPath = "\\zts-fs1\kv$\Merné\Naposledy_merane_zily\"
 Dim R$
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim test As String
 Dim rowsCount as integer

 Application.ScreenUpdating=false
 test = "Otvor test!"
 R = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("linky_zila").UsedRange), "|")
 Set myFolder = DSO.GetFolder(sPath)
 rowsCount=Rows.count
 With Sheets("test_zila")
 For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
   For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
    DoEvents
    If Not (InStr(1, R, myFile.Path) > 0) Then

        GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "D4:D5", .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False

        GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "S4:S5", .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)), True, False

        GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "A8:A9", .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)), True, False

        GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "E8:E9", .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4)), True, False

        GetData myFile, "Vystupna_kontrola", "F8:F9", .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5)), True, False


        .Range("U3", "U50000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm"
        .Range("V3", "V50000").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

        .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 25).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 25), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 25).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 25)).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & myFile.Path & """ ,""" & test & """)"

        Sheets("linky_zila").Cells(Sheets("linky_zila").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = myFile.Path
        R = R & myFile.Path & "|"

       For i = 1 To 23
           If .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i)).Value = "" Then
               .Range(.Cells(.Cells(rowsCount, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i), .Cells(.Cells(rowsCount,  1).End(xlUp).Row, 1 + i)).Value = "/"
            End If
        Next
    End If
  Next
 Next
 End With
 Set DSO = Nothing
 Set myFolder = Nothing
 Set mySubFolder = Nothing
 Set myFile = Nothing
 Application.ScreenUpdating=True
End Sub
```